# Sort eloquent model with eager loaded relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to build a small application where I am having three models, I want to sort the model by column inside the eager load relationship, for this I have a model named `AssociatedCompany` as:

```php
class AssociateCompany extends Model {

    protected $table = 'project_associate_company';

    protected $fillable = [
        'project_id', 'company_role_id', 'company_specialisation_id', 'company_id', 'link', 'file_name'
    ];

   public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','project_id','id');
    }

    public function companyRole()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'company_role_id','id');
    }
}
```

and other model `Role` as :

```php
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table='company_role';

    protected $fillable = [
        'sl', 'name', 'parent_id'
    ];

}
```

Now I want to fetch all the companies of related project and sort them out with `sl` of role, for this I am trying to do a `join` something like this:

```php
$companies = Project\AssociateCompany::whereHas('project', function ($q) use($request) {
    $q->where('slug', $request->slug);
})
    ->with('companyRole')
    ->join('company_role', 'project_associate_company.id', '=', 'company_role.project_associate_company_id')
    ->orderBy('company_role.sl', 'desc')
    ->paginate(20);
```

So in this I am getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company_role.project_associate_company_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `project_associate_company` inner join `company_role` on `project_associate_company`.`id` = `company_role`.`project_associate_company_id` where exists (select * from `projects` where `project_associate_company`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` and `slug` = kovacek-rodriguez and `projects`.`deleted_at` is null) and `project_associate_company`.`deleted_at` is null)

Help me out in this.

Comment: Does your `company_role` table have a `project_associate_company_id` column on it? This error looks to be thrown by `->join('company_role', 'project_associate_company.id', '=', 'company_role.project_associate_company_id')`

Comment: @TimLewis no, it has `sl`, `name`, and `parent_id` along with the timestamps.

Comment: Then there's your answer; fix your `join` clause or add that column.

Comment: Awesome; feel free to post an answer if you think it will help someone else in the future. Cheers.